# Google games api. How to get list of games which user played?

Tags: google-api, google-play, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-play-services-3.3.0

Is it possible to get a list of games which user played using Google play games services and get some stats from them like XP and achievements(with WEB API)?

I didn't find any info in documentation but have seen some sites which display the achievements like -> https://www.exophase.com .
I understand that this question was already asked in 2017 but still no info. I tried web-api and i need only answers about web-api.
Please hepl me

Comment: Would you be able to provide any information around any research you've come across so far? That may help others provide a useful answer :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.